# Angular - The interceptor class local variable not reflecting change inside intercept function

Tags: angular, frontend, interceptor, angular-services

My intercept class has a token as a local variable.
[image]

I have a function autoLogin() in the same file (interceptor)

[image]

This autoLogin is called in ngOnInit of app.component.ts.

This is my intercept.

[image]

Note line 21, printing token to the console.

**Problem:** Since the autoLogin function is called first the token from the local storage is assigned to the local variable token. (printed in line 94). So the print at line 21 which is called after autoLogin should print the token but it is printing '' (empty string, init value).

**Output**
[image]

*Note: 3 HTTP calls are made.*

Comment: Is your interceptor a singleton? Also, is there other code path that will modify the `token`?

Comment: Multi is set to true in providers. The token is used only inside the interceptor class, nowhere outside.

Comment: Quoting the official [doc](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) : `If you import HttpClientModule multiple times across different modules (for example, in lazy loading modules), each import creates a new copy of the HttpClientModule, which overwrites the interceptors provided in the root module.` So most likely, your interceptors are different instances. You could either use the method suggest by the doc to use a shared single instance, or inject another service to store the token state. Personally I believe the latter is simpler.